# What is the simplest cellular automaton that simulates simple particle physics?

Tags: javascript, automation, computation-theory, particle-system, computability

Mind the following particle physics animation:

```js
var atoms = [{pos:10, vel:1.2913513}, {pos:20,vel:0}, {pos:24, vel:-2}, {pos:60,vel:0}, {pos: 60, vel:0}];
setInterval(function(){
    var has_atom = {};
    for (var i=0, l=atoms.length; i<l; ++i){
        for (var j=0; j<l; ++j)
            atoms[i].vel += (atoms[j].pos - atoms[i].pos) * 0.005;
        atoms[i].pos += atoms[i].vel;
        has_atom[~~atoms[i].pos] = true;
    };
    for (var image=" ", i=0; i<72; ++i)
        image += has_atom[i] ? "O" : "_";
    document.getElementById("atoms").innerHTML = image;
}, 25);
```

```html
<div id="atoms" style="font-family: monospace"></div>
```

It, while simple, involves action at distance: i.e., at each tick, atoms interact with other arbitrarily far atoms. That isn't possible with cellular automatons, which only have local rules. Thus, I wonder: **what is the simplest automata encoding on which can display similarly looking particle physics behavior?**

Comment: You can try to ask on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/